# qgis python + layout/template + exporting in .png + filtering layers

Tags: pyqgis, filter, layouts

I need to do a lot of pictures at different points from vector layer on each. And the picture (.jpg / .png) must be signed and so on - then the layout is best suited. Now I do a picture on a map posted on the points (and even get .png) how to create a layout with the data or work from the layout and apply it using a filter python?

My code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setSubsetString('')
iter = layer.getFeatures()
for feature in iter:
    name_dot = feature['name']
    saving = "C:/project_qgis/"+"%s"%name_dot+".png"
    print saving
    layer.setSubsetString('"name"=\'%s\'' % name_dot) 
    mapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
    c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
    c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
    x, y = 0, 0
    w = c.paperWidth()
    h = c.paperHeight()
    composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, x ,y, w, h)
    c.addItem(composerMap)
    dpi = c.printResolution()
    dpmm = dpi / 25.4
    width = int(dpmm *w)
    height = int(dpmm *h)
    image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
    image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
    image.fill(0)
    imagePainter = QPainter(image)
    sourceArea = QRectF(0, 0, w, h)
    targetArea = QRectF(0, 0, width, height)
    c.render(imagePainter, targetArea, sourceArea)
    imagePainter.end()
    image.save("%s" %saving, "png")
```

In fact, the biggest problem is the size of the image, scale, degree grid and the label on the finished picture that can be done during layout...

Comment: Did you look at the atlas functionality of the print composer?

Comment: Yes. i  had solve it already